# Dynamic Range Formulas

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, sum, range

I have some data that I extracted from another workbook and I would like to sum the column at the end of the data. The problem is that I want the sum formula in the last cell, not just the value, so that if a user changes the data after it has been extracted, it will update automatically. The data starts in row 8 and will vary in length so here is what I tried so far:

```
  ActiveCell.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Select
  LastRow = Activecell.Row
  ActiveCell.Offset(2,0).Range("a1").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R[-LastRow + 6]C:R[-2]C)"
```

This returns an error because I guess you cannot use a variable in this syntax. What can I do?

Comment: Must the formula be at the end of the column?  If it could be in an adjacent column, you could simply use =SUM($A:$A) in some cell.  If it must be at the end of the column, as you insert rows to add more data, a formula such as =SUM($A$1:$A$10) should adjust accordingly.

Comment: The formula must be at the end of the column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of your code is correct then change the last line to:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R[-" & Cstr(LastRow+6) & "]C:R[-2]C)"
```

Comment: I am getting error 1004, application-defined or object-defined error, with this code.

Comment: Whats the value of LastRow?